# Python 3.6.5 - How do I update packages globally, so that they are updated in future Virtual environments?

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6.5 on windows and I have upgraded the version of Pip to 10.0.1 and the setup tools to 39.0.1.

However whenever I create a new virtual environment I have to upgrade pip and setup tools again.

Is there any way that I can update packages in the main installation of python so that they are reflected in any virtual instance I create?

Comment: If you are on linux, I think `sudo apt-get upgrade` should do the task

Comment: Your first sentence seems to be missing a bit before "6.5 and [...]". Please [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: Sorry not sure what happened there - I have edited my post - thanks